# How do I determine how many of my webpages rank on 1st page of Google, and for what terms?

Tags: seo, google, keywords, ranking

How do I find out how many pages of a website ranks on the first page of Google? And for what terms?

I mean, if the website has 100 webpages, I want to know:

- How many pages rank on first page (shown on first page of Google)
- Which specific keyword they rank.

Answer (score 2):

There's no comprehensive way to determine exactly what terms will trigger a 1st page result (as this will depend on [way too many factors](http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors)), but you can use various software to check whatever terms you want against the results in Google and get their positions.

[Advanced Web Rankings](http://www.advancedwebranking.com/) and similar software can do this for you.

It's also important to remember that in this day and age, localisation and [personalisation](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/09/search-privacy-and-personalized-search.html) will significantly impact what results are shown for any given query. So you should always take that into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

If you subscribe to Google Webmaster Tools, you can find out the [average](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35252) [position of your site pages within Google search results page along with the specified keywords that were used](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/05/top-search-queries-is-now-search.html).

Comment: +1 I use that all the time, but forgot at the time of answering!